# How to make .dot file to .jpeg/png/gif conversion faster by using graphviz on command line?

Tags: performance, graphviz, dot

I have a couple of .dot extension files, however, the files are quite big. What I want to do is to get a visual of these .dot extension files by converting them into .jpeg, .png, .gif.

While I do this process, I do it from the command line, so I don't use any GUI.

The problem is, when I start the conversion process I can't get any result or progress. I checked the process through task manager and it seems to be there is no progress after a certain moment.

Is it possible to speed up the process instead of increasing or modifying the computer hardware.

Any suggestion or alternatives would be helpful,

Thanks.

Comment: No error messages in the console? Did you try the `-v` switch in order to get verbose output and see what's going on? It may help to add some information about your dot files (size, number of nodes/edges, sample, ...) and the exact command line you're using.

Comment: I don't receive any error message. I run the command below to get the image

"dot dotFile.dot -Tjpeg -o jpegFile.jpeg"

I haven't tried to get the verbose output, but I will definitely try it out.

Comment: Did it not create the jpegFile.jpeg file after it was done?  Sorry if that's too obvious.

Comment: Normally it does create a jpeg file for smaller size .dot files. However, for my case, the .dot files were around 1.00MB-to-2.50MB and it couldn't create it. Maybe "couldn't create it" is not the correct answer, but the process was taking too long, so I couldn't wait much longer and halted the process. So I think I would say I am not sure if it will really create it or not.

Comment: Did `-v` give you any information? You may try starting with a smaller version of your script, optimize it, and then gradually add more nodes. Try not to create huge jpegs. Try creating dot output first (text, no image rendering).